# combining trained neural nets in tensorflow

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow to train two instances of the same neural network with two different datasets. the network itself is quite simple with an input and output layer and 6 hidden layers (each layer is a 20 meurons followed by a non-linear activation function).

I can train the network with two different datasets and that is fine. Now, what i want to do is basically create a new network which is a combination of these two trained networks. In particular, I want the input and the first 3 layers to be from one of the trained network and the last 3 layers and the output layer to be from the other network. I am very new to tensorflow and have not found a way to do this. Can someone point me to the API or some way to do this sort of hybrid networks?

Comment: Follow the procedure for transfer learning but do not retrain the last layers and you will have this. I think this is quite possible with Keras but I don't know if that will give good results

Answer (score 1):

It seems merging two neural networks does not make any sense. You may instead train one deep R-CNN or with just 2 different NN trained, You may classify as for a test case,if outputs of both NN agree, then output the common output, else the NN which outputs 1, its precision and NN which outputs -1, ratio of its correct negatives to total cases which it predicted negative(calculated in training), whichever is greater, output that NN's output.

Hope these articles will help you.

[Build Your First Deep Learning Classifier using TensorFlow: Dog Breed Example](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-first-deep-learning-classifier-using-tensorflow-dog-breed-example-964ed0689430)

[Deep Learning Part 3: Combining Deep Convolutional Neural Network with Recurrent Neural Network](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/09/deep-learning-part-3.html)